# Avoid Repeated Includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to entity framework. I have an entity `A` which has many-to-many relationship with other entities.
In the repository used to get an entity `A`, I use the following code:

```
_dbContext.Set<A>.Where(a => a.Id == id).Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(b=>b.C).Include(a=>a.D)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

In entite's X repo, I use the following:

```
_dbContext.Set<X>.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x=>x.As).ThenInclude(a => a.B).ThenInclude(b=>b.C)
.Include(x=>x.As).Include(a=>a.D).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

So if for entities Y and Z, I have to write the same includes/thenIncludes.

Is there a way to have these includes in just one place and use them in the different repos?

Comment: [AutoInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations)?

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about it. I will give it a try